# I bought Tokens Using Metamask But I need MyEtherWallet to See Them - How Do I Do This?

Tags: myetherwallet, metamask

Please can you help.

I bought tokens using Metamask and I am advised that the tokens can be seen in MyEtherWallet but I am not sure what to do next.

1. Do I need to set up a new MyEtherWallet account?
2. MyEtherWallet say I can access my account using "Mnemonic Phrase" from Metamask, what is this phrase as I don't remember setting such a phrase when installing Metamask?

Thank you in advance and best regards,

Comment: I have Metamask and used it to buy some EOS. Now that I want to try to retrieve my tokens, I can't see the icons on my Metamask that are used to access the EOS site where my tokens are supposed to be. I thin it was a key icon. I used these icons when I bought the EOS. Anyone now why the icons are not visible on my mask or where I might find them? Or perhaps how to connect to EOS via Metamask to retrieve EOS coins?

Answer (score 1):

1. MetaMask is adding token viewing very soon, so you could just wait a day or two.
2. MetaMask can already be used to view tokens using a variety of token-viewing websites: https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/USERS.md#managing-tokens

If you still want to move to MEW to use tokens, there are two ways:

1. Import your MetaMask seed phrase into MEW. It's the phrase MetaMask showed you when you first created your vault, and said "Make sure you write this down". You can also recover it from the settings view in MetaMask, in the top right menu.
2. You can export an individual private key from MetaMask by clicking the key icon.